# SQL: insert a new row with columns that have default value

Tags: sql

Is it possible in SQL to leave out default values for chosen columns, for instance:  ps = conn.prepareStatement("insert into table values (default,?,default)") ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
"insert into some_table (some_column) values (?)"
```

Simply leave out the columns for which you want default values.